# How do I decode received data from supabase in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase

In Dart/Flutter, using the supabase package, I'm trying to decode the data I receive for example from the following code:

```
final data = await supabase
  .from('countries')
  .select('''
    name,
    cities (
      name
    )
  ''');
```

How do I do that? Can anyone provide me with an example how I get the resulting Dart objects out of data? How would I e.g. print the table that I get as result?

Code taken from the documentation: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/select

I tried to decode it as if I would decode json but it did not work.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data that you get, and what problem you have when you do the json decode?

Comment: @DhafinRayhan please see my answer including an output below. Any ideas on how to get the data from data in fetchData(), if I e.g. would want to use it for analysis purposes without building a widget?

Comment: The returned data is `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` by default. The data is decoded by the supabase_flutter library, and you do not need to json decode it by yourself.

Comment: Now I get it, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is little code that explain how to use supabase data

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Countries',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final _future = Supabase.instance.client
      .from('countries')
      .select();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        future: _future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          final countries = snapshot.data!;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: countries.length,
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
              final country = countries[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(country['name']),
              );
            }),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

See [Use Supabase with Flutter](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/quickstarts/flutter) for details.

For fetching data without future builder.
Method 2.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Countries',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
List countries = [];


@override
void initState(){
getCountryData();
super.initState();
}


void  getCountryData()async{
List data = await Supabase.instance.client
      .from('countries')
      .select()
setState((){
countries.addAll(data);
});


}


  final _future = Supabase.instance.client
      .from('countries')
      .select();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:  countries.isNotEmpty ?ListView.builder(
            itemCount: countries.length,
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
              final country = countries[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(country['name']),
              );
):const SizedBox.shrink()
}       
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works and gets done what I originally intended. However, I'm still not sure, how to get the data, without actually building a widget, e.g. just to for example run an analysis on it.

Comment: Any ideas on how to get it are appreciated :)

Comment: Yes you can call your function in initstate that fetch data from supabase, see I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fully solves my problem and answers my questions!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows (see notes below):

```
   PostgrestTransformBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> get _future =>
         Supabase.instance.client
             .from('saved')
             .select()
             .eq('profile_id', supabase.auth.currentUser!.id)
             .order('importance', ascending: false)
             .limit(2);
   
     void fetchData() async {
       try {
         final data = supabase
             .from('saved')
             .select()
             .eq('profile_id', supabase.auth.currentUser!.id)
             .order('importance', ascending: false)
             .limit(2);
         print(data);
         print(jsonDecode(data.toString()));
       } catch (e) {
         print('Fetch error: $e');
       }
     }
   
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
           title: const Text('Test'),
           actions: [
             TextButton(
                 onPressed: () => setState(() {}),
                 child: const Text('Refresh')),
             TextButton(
                 onPressed: () => fetchData(),
                 child: const Text('Fetch data')),
           ],
         ),
         body: FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
           future: _future,
           builder: (context, snapshot) {
             if (!snapshot.hasData) {
               return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
             }
             final savedItems = snapshot.data!;
             return ListView.builder(
               itemCount: savedItems.length,
               itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                 final item = savedItems[index];
                 return ListTile(
                   title: Text(item['pos']),
                 );
               }),
             );
           },
         ),
       );
     }
```

Please note:

- The FutureBuilder builds the widget as intended. This solves my initial problem.
- Hitting the 'Fetch' button just gets the data, which unfortunately, I still don't know how to decode. As output I get: "Instance of 'PostgrestTransformBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>'\n Fetch error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'I', "Instance o"... is not valid JSON"

Comment: because fetchData() is an async function but you forgot to put the await keyword.

here:  Future<void> fetchData() async {
       try {
         final data = await supabase
             .from('saved')
             .select()
             .eq('profile_id', supabase.auth.currentUser!.id)
             .order('importance', ascending: false)
             .limit(2);
         print(data);
         print(jsonDecode(data.toString()));
       } catch (e) {
         print('Fetch error: $e');
       }
     }